# How would I go about finding the average of a set of integers from a for loop (in C++)

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm prompting the user to enter an integer for x (between 3 and 10), and  enter integer y (between 6 and 20). Then, I'm supposed to have the values for said numbers printed out, and find an average for them.

```
while (x < 3 || x > 10) 
while (y < 6 || y > 20)
```

Say the user enters: x = 3 and y = 6

The set (range of integers) would be (3 4 5 6)

Now I have to find the average between them, without the user entering in the number for how big the set is

Comment: The values are stored in a [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)? Then [std::set::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/size). Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE and errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question

Comment: `std::accumulate`, then divide by `s.size()`. Look at cppreference.com .

Comment: Here is a link with example [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: What do you mean by "set" exactly? Do you mean a range of integers? Also, please show some input/output examples. Also, please show all the code that you have written.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your expected set supposed to look like when the user enters x=10, y=6 ? Will it be {6 7 8 9 10} ?

Comment: If the set contains every integer number between a to b, then this set is called an "interval". The average of the numbers is a+b/2. Of course if there are gaps, this no longer holds.

Comment: Hint:   what does the expression `y - x + 1` give?    Second hint:  the sum of all integers between `1` and `n` inclusive is `n*(n+1)/2`.      Using those two hints, it is not necessary to use a loop at all.

Comment: If by "set" you really mean the *range* of values between `x` and `y`, then you can easily calculate the number of values. Then use a `for` loop to sum all numbers. Then divide the sum with the number of values. It's really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a `for` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter first number: ";
  int minimum;
  cin >> minimum;
  cout << "Enter second number: ";
  int maximum; 
  cin >> maximum;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = minimum; i <= maximum; ++i)
  {
      sum += i;
  }
  double average = (sum * 1.0) / (maximum - minimum + 1.0);
  cout << "average is: " << average << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

*Note:  Your post title says `for` loop, but your post content has `while`*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple trick. The average of the numbers

```
x + (x + 1) + ... + (y - 1) + y == (x + y) / 2.0
```

You don't need a loop for the average.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  unsigned int x;
  do {
    std::cout << "x: ";
    std::cin >> x;
  } while (x < 3 || x > 10);
  unsigned int y;
  do {
    std::cout << "y: ";
    std::cin >> y;
  } while (y < 6 || y > 20);

  for (auto i = x; i <= y; ++i) {
      std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
  double average = (x + y) / 2.0;
  cout << "average is: " << average << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```